# FInding real roots of a polynomial and transcendental equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, transcendental-equations

Show that if $$Z = 2(-H^\frac{1}{2})\cos(\theta),$$ where $Z$ is a root of the cubic equation $$Z^3 + 3HZ+G=0,$$ then $$\cos(3\theta) = \sqrt{-G^2/4H^3}.$$
Deduce that if the $H < 0$, and $G^2+4H^3 < 0$ the cubic equation has three real roots. By using the expression $\cos(3\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{3j\theta}+e^{-3j\theta})$, solve the equation when $G^2+4H^3> 0$, treating seperately the cases $H < 0$ and $H > 0.$

[Part of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQLbG.jpg)
[Part 2 of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2GtP.jpg)

Now for the other parts of the questions, I don't know how to go about it

Comment: **You** have to show it, not us. Show your work, please.

Comment: For lots of advice on asking a crowd-pleasing question, you should consult: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959  Welcome to Mathematics Stack.

Comment: Okay, so I have been able to show how this equation $cos (3\theta) = \sqrt{-G^2/4H^3}$.
was gotten